# Matplotlib lower graph always in front

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I would like to make 2 graphs on one plot. 
I would like the lower one to always be in the front, regardless of which one is lower.

Thank you in advance for help.

```
plt.plot([1,2,3], a)
plt.plot([1,2,3], b)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the parameter `zorder`. Use,

```
plt.plot([1,2,3], a, zorder=1)
plt.plot([1,2,3], b, zorder=0)
plt.show()
```

The `zorder` is like a sequence order. Providing `0` and `1` will put the second plot with `zorder=0` in the background and bring the first plot with `zorder=1` to the front.

Comment: I don't want a fixed parameter. I need the lower column in front regardless of whether a or b column is lower.

Comment: @Dawid: In that case, you would need some if statement which first sets the zorder and then use it in the plot command